# Python with tox. How to setup install_command for one dependecy only

Tags: python, tox

Hello I'm trying to use Tox to setup my testing enviroment.

What is the problem I would like to solve?

I have few servers running tests with different network setups (different ip, different interfaces names etc.) so I have prepared module which have all the configs and I do install it using server number i.e.

```
pip install . --install-option="--serverNumber=102"
```

This way in my environment i have only one configuration and I can import it in test without knowing anything about actual server test is running on.

Right now I'm trying to use tox to set up virtual env and I have problem because I don;t know how to define specific install_command only for one dependecy? 
I don;t even know if it is possible.

Thank you in advace for help

BR
Krzysztof

Answer (score 2):

list your dependencies in he deps section and install `foobar` separately:

```
[testenv]
deps =
   dep1
   dep2
   dep3
   ....

commands =
   pip install foobar --install-option="--serverNumber={posargs}"
   py.test
```

if you launch tox as

```
tox -- 102
```

will execute:

```
pip install foobar --install-option="--serverNumber=102"
```

Answer (score -1):

How about this:

1. Run `pip install` for the whole requirements set.
2. Then uninstall the particular package and reinstall with with `pip install foobar` passing in the extra installation options.

-

```
  pip uninstall foobar
  pip install foobar --install-option="--serverNumber=102"
```

Comment: Where I should run this additional commands? Should it be somehow still inside tox script?